# Run an Executable by nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, electron

I want to run an executable by using nodeJS.Followings are my tries to achieve this.

- I am using electronJS for Gui, I used electron-pacakger to compile JS file.
- My goal is to call a EXE from electron packed Executable, so that my server will be triggered.

**MY Try:**

*main.js*

```
var subpy = require('child_process').execFile("C:\\datajr\\datajr.exe");
```

**2nd Try:**

I referred some QA in stack from there i got a solution like below:

```
var child = require('child_process').execFile;
  var executablePath = "C:\\datajr\\datajr.exe";

   child(executablePath, function(err, data) {
        if(err){
           console.error(err);
           return;
        }

    console.log(data.toString());
});
```

- When i trigger command `npm start` my `electron JS` along with `datajr.exe` has to execute. But unfortunately its not happening.

Comment: Does it work if you test with `node yourscript.js` ?

Comment: its starting only if i give command npm start only @Frederik.L . Since i have integrated with electron quick start.  quickstart[1]

Comment: https://electronjs.org/docs/tutorial/quick-start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose you want to run the electron app and another executable at the same time, in that case you can use [concurrently](https://www.npmjs.com/package/concurrently).
Suppose you can execute the executable directly from the commandline like `datajr` then you can modify your `package.json` by adding :

```
"scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "concurrently \"datajr\" \"electron main.js\" ",
  }
```

Now `npm start` to start the electron app and the executable. In this way you can overcome the hustle of executing the file from within the `main.js`.

Comment: But using concurrently how to go to the path  "c:\datajr\dist\datajr.exe" ?

Comment: windows : `"start": "concurrently \"cd /\d C:\\datajr\\dist &&  datajr.exe\" \"sleep 2 && electron main.js\" "`

Comment: Getting Error when i gave path : npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token d in JSON at position 141 while parsing near '...co
rrently \"cd /\d C:\\dev_sky\\core_...'  @Boo

Comment: Must be a typo :
"start": "concurrently \"cd \/d C:\\datajr\\dist && datajr.exe\" \"sleep 2 && electron main.js\" "

Comment: sleep 2 && electron main.js exited with code 1 error is coming any idea ?

Comment: is your electron app starting from main.js ?

Comment: yea , im package.json i have written : "start" : "electron ."

Comment: so change it to `"start": "concurrently \"cd \/d C:\\datajr\\dist && datajr.exe\" \"sleep 2 && electron .\" "`

Comment: still sleep 2 error @Boo. And fortunately exe is running fine.

Comment: 'sleep' is not recognized as an internal o
 operable program or batch file.
 sleep 2 && electron . exited with code 1

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173954/discussion-between-boo-and-frank-hk). This will work then `"start": "concurrently \"cd \/d C:\\datajr\\dist && datajr.exe\" \" electron .\" " `

Comment: @Boo thanks for helpin him in chat. Helped me figure out how to start Pocketbase backend AND electron.

Answer (score 0):

From the npm Documentation:

> `npm start` runs an arbitrary command specified in the package's "start" property of its "scripts" object (in your `package.json` file). If no "start" property is specified on the "scripts" object, it will run node server.js.

So, if you don't have a `package.json` in the directory of your project or it doesn't include your `main.js` in the `start` property of `scripts`, `npm start` won't work.

If you want to know more about this, check the npm documentation:

For `npm start`: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/start

For the `package.json` file: https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json

Comment: I have package.json in my folder, i have already specified what you recommended in package.json @Álvaro Tihanyi

Comment: What i want is to make run an external exe from mani,js, any idea ? @Álvaro Tihanyi